# Using RxJava to update UI thread with time elapsed from a service

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a long running service that collects data from the users sensors in the background. What I want to do is to display the total elapsed time in the UI-thread periodically, like every other 30 seconds (or whenever the user triggers the onCreate).

Right now, my solution has been to start a TimerTask that sends a Local BroadcastIntent to the Activity (obviously a bad solution, though it works).

So my second thought was that maybe I could (start to) use RxJava for this task. I know that there is something called an interval in RxJava, and I managed to create a Log spitout every second with this:

```
int mSeconds = 0;

Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                        .map(s -> mSeconds++)
                        .subscribe( s -> Log.d("TAG", s.toString()));
```

So my question, finally:

1) How do implement this solution in a respectable manner taking into consideration that I have batched the sensor evens up to 10 secs.

Comment: Wouldn't an AsyncTask accoomplish the same thing. It has a method to post updates from the background thread to the ui thread so you can show advance.

Comment: @Juan Please do not suggest Async Task

Comment: @Rinav can you esplain why?

Comment: @Juan There are so many pitfalls of using Async task. A simple search will lead you to the Horror stories of using Async tasks. You can find out more from this [excellent blog post from Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/)

Comment: @Rinav, if you use AsyncTask correctly you don't run into these "pitfalls". There are no horror stories. You just have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own custom Timer that is a Singleton class. This Timer should have a

- `start()` method that starts a TimerTask
- `stop()` method that stops the same TimerTask
- `register(Callback callback)` method for listeners or subscribers
- `unregister(Callback callback)` method for listeners or subscribers

With Dependency Injection (maybe [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html)) you could provide this custom timer as a shared object.

**Idea** is to create it as a Singleton that is provided by your Application class. E.g. via `((YourApplication) getApplicationContext()).getTimer()` you can call this instance in your Activity and your Service.

Your **Service** would take care of starting and stopping this Timer and your **Activity** can register in its `onStart()` and unregister in its `onStop()` method as a callback to this custom Timer.

The Timer should probably also contain the **Callback** implementation maybe with a `onTimeUpdate(long millis)` method.

I hope you get the idea!

Comment: I do get the idea. Thanks